# HTML in textview

Tags: cocoa

I am using textview in cocoa
How we show a HTML data in textview

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say if you're targeting the Mac or the iPhone. I'll assume the Mac since you tagged your question with cocoa.

It would be worth looking into the [Text System documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/TextArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000086) for an overview of how `NSTextView` works. But at a basic level, all `NSTextView`s have an `NSTextStorage` object (accessible via the `textStorage` method) `NSTextStorage` happens to be a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

`NSAttributedString` has an initializer called [`initWithHTML:baseURL:documentAttributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJDADJC) which will parse an HTML string for you. Once you've got that, you can append the resulting string to your `NSTextView`'s `textStorage`. For example:

```
NSData *htmlData = // get the html, e.g. from a file
NSURL *aBaseURL = // a URL used to resolve relative links e.g. '/directory/page.html'
NSAttributedString *formattedHTML = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData baseURL:aBaseURL documentAttributes:NULL];
[[myTextView textStorage] appendAttributedString:formattedHTML];
[formattedHTML release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an UIWebView and fill it with a string instead of a webpage.

Comment: UIWebView is Cocoa-Touch, so this only applies to iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (part of the WebKit framework)? Although NSTextView has rudimentary HTML support, WebView gives you all of the power of the modern, standards-compliant, WebKit framework.

Answer (score 0):

If macOS NSTextView

Swift 5:

```swift
let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8)!
if let attributedString = NSAttributedString(html: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) 
{
      textView.textStorage?.append(attributedString)
      textView.textColor = .labelColor
      textView.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
}
```